# i cant create child domain users after adding child domain zone in active directory

Tags: active-directory

first i have created one active directory with some domain name. then for the sake of my project work i need another domain zone in that active directory.through Domain zone option i can created that child domain.. but it is not there in my active directory domains and trust option. i cant see that new domain in domains list and that too i want to create user for that newly added child domain zone..

Comment: To clarify: Did you create a child domain or a child DNS zone?

Comment: What do you mean by "project work" ? Is this at your place of employment, or for a class or self-directed learning project?

Answer (score 1):

sounds like you added a child DNS Zone and didn't do Install-ADDSDomainController. Adding the DNS Zone will not create a child domain. Only building a second server and promoting it to a domain controller will create a child domain. The ADDS promotion will add the DNS Zone for you and setup the trusts and sites.